# XSLT refuses to alter source - strips tags only

Tags: xml, xslt, translation

Given this XML source:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<modsCollection xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/mods/" 
    xmlns:mods="http://www.loc.gov/mods/" version="3.0">
<mods xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mods="http://www.loc.gov/mods/" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/mods/ http://www.loc.gov/standards/mods/mods.xsd">
  <titleInfo>
      <title>Mutant sex party :</title>
      <subTitle>&amp; other plays</subTitle>
  </titleInfo>
  <name type="personal">
      <namePart xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/TR/xlink">Macdonald, Ed</namePart>
        <role>
          <text>creator</text>
        </role>
    </name>
</mods>
</modsCollection>
```

And given this XSL stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/> 

    <xsl:template match="/modsCollection">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="mods" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="mods">
    <ul>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="titleInfo" />
    </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="title">
        <li><xsl:value-of select="." /></li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I should be getting an UL list of titles. Instead I am getting back the stripped text nodes only.  What gives?  Have I done something stupid in here somewhere ?

~ Erik

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to take the default namespace `xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/mods/"` into account, using an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or AltovaXML it suffices to put `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.loc.gov/mods/"` on your `xsl:stylesheet` element.

With an XSLT 1.0 processor you need to change your code to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:df="http://www.loc.gov/mods/"
    exclude-result-prefixes="df"

    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/> 

    <xsl:template match="/df:modsCollection">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="df:mods" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="df:mods">
    <ul>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="df:titleInfo" />
    </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="df:title">
        <li><xsl:value-of select="." /></li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3):

The root element in your source document says

```
<modsCollection xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/mods/"
```

Therefore it (and all its unprefixed descendants) are in this namespace, and will *not* match

```
    <xsl:template match="/modsCollection">
```

You need to add an `xmlns:mods` declaring this namespace to your `xsl:stylesheet` element, and use the prefix in your template match expressions and `apply-templates` select expressions

```
    <xsl:template match="/mods:modsCollection">
```